# почему то переменная типа int показывается как str

Tags: python, int

извините если вопрос покажется глупым, но почему в данном коде переменная показывается как тип str?Почему не тип int?[image: вот он, сам код]

Comment: Функция input принимает строку подсказки и возвращает строку, в вашем случае подсказка выглядит как `int()` т.к. внутри input. А то, что вы хотели сделать, нужно делать наоборот: `int(input())`.

Comment: Вы неправильно написали выражение `int(input())`. `input(string)` - это функция, которая сначала выводит в консоль свой аргумент string, а потом считывает строку введенную пользователем. В данном случае, вы создаете пустой объект int(), который равен 0. Далее он выводится в консоль, после чего пользователь пишет свой ввод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что функция `input()` ВСЕГДА возвращает только строку (см. документацию)

т.е. формат функции `input` такой:

```
text = input(prompt)
```

в качестве параметра функция принимает то, что она выводит пользователю, а в качестве вывода выдает строку, введённую пользователем

если вам нужно число, то вывод надо преобразовать в число

```
num = int(input("введите число:"))
```

**P.S.**

в вашем коде кстати `input(int())` будет делать следующее:

1. сначала отработает `int()`, что даст 0
2. затем будет выполнен код `input(0)`, что выведет на экран 0 и будет ожидаться ввод от пользователя

Comment: спасибо, помогли